# In ColdFusion UDFs is there a way to reference a variable from the parent function scope?

Tags: scope, coldfusion, user-defined-functions

If you have a situation where one UDF  calls another UDF inside it, is it possible to reference the parent's local scope without passing it as an argument?  My instincts tell me that this is impossible as the local scope of a function is **supposed** to be isolated by design.

For example:

```
<cffunction name="function01">

     <cfset var fruit = "apple" />

     <cfset function02() />

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="function02">

     <cfdump var="#fruit#" /> <!--- can I reference fruit? --->

</cffunction>
```

The only way I know how to give function02 access to the parent UDF's local scope variables is to pass it as an argument. Of course you could also use the REQUEST, FORM, URL, SESSION, and APPLICATION scopes as well I suppose.

```
<cffunction name="function01">

     <cfset var fruit = "apple" />

     <cfset function02(fruit) />

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="function02">

     <cfargument name="fruit" />

     <cfdump var="#fruit#" />

</cffunction>
```

Comment: using an argument seems like it'd be the correct choice, why wouldn't you want to do it that way?

Comment: This is more for the sake of curiosity.  I know with <cfmodule> tags you can use the CALLER scope.  I didn't see any reference to anything like this for <cffunction> tags.

Comment: If the two functions are in the same file, take away the word `var` in function01.  Of course, that changes the question because it would no longer be the parent's local scope.

Comment: *I didn't see any reference to anything like this for <cffunction> tags* Well, it is like you said: The scope is deliberately designed to be isolated. So there *shouldn't* be a documented way to do what you are asking. Just use the arguments scope as others mentioned.

Comment: If it's a static variable, you could move it out of the function and into the component. Then just use the `this` tag instead of making it a local scope. You can then call the `this.var` in both of the functions needed.

Comment: Keep in mind the `this` scope is public, and can be modified from outside the component which is often undesirable. Usually, placing a static variable in the `variables` scope of the component should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on everyone's comments the correct answer is that you can not reference a local scoped variable from a child function.  The only way to pass the reference on is to either pass the variable(s) as arguments to the child function or to store the variables in a different scope (e.g. VARIABLES, FORM, URL, REQUEST, SESSION, APPLICATION, SERVER, etc...)

The preferred method is to pass the variable(s) as arguments to the child function:

```
<cffunction name="function01">

     <cfset var fruit = "apple" />

     <cfset function02(fruit) />

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="function02">

     <cfargument name="fruit" />

     <cfdump var="#fruit#" />

</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 1):

By declaring `fruit` with `var` in front of it, its only available to the local scope (within the function).

try:

```
<cffunction name="function01">

     <cfset fruit = "apple" />

     <cfset function02() />

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="function02">

     <cfdump var="#fruit#" /> <!--- can I reference fruit? --->

</cffunction>
```

This might work, but it's not the "clean" way of handling this, better work with arguments